# Adding GeoServer vector WMS layers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have been trying to add my WMS vector layers in OpenLayers 3 but it isn't working, I guess there is a problem with my script.
Below is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    var view = new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([7.118906, 5.640610]),
      zoom: 8
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map'
    });

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            preload: Infinity,
            url: 'http://localhost:8090/geoserver/ssterritory/wms',
            serverType:'geoserver',
            params:{
                'LAYERS':"ssterritory:lgas", 'TILED':true
            }
        })
    });

    map.addLayer(osmLayer);
    map.addLayer(lgas);
    map.setView(view);
</script>
```

I need someone to help me with this

Comment: it looks like you never add vectorLayer to the map

Comment: Note that WMS is not a vector layer

Answer (score 3):

As per the @IanTurton comment you are never add your WMS layer to the map, like 'map.addLayer(vectorLayer);' in the below code:

```
<script>
    var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    var view = new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([7.118906, 5.640610]),
      zoom: 8
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map'
    });

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            preload: Infinity,
            url: 'http://localhost:8090/geoserver/ssterritory/wms',
            serverType:'geoserver',
            params:{
                'LAYERS':"ssterritory:lgas", 'TILED':true
            }
        })
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer); // --> add this to your code
    map.addLayer(osmLayer);
    map.addLayer(lgas);
    map.setView(view);
</script>
```